# How to test correlated (coupled) methods in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Let's say we have class:

```
class Post
  def save
    # implementation
  end

  def self.find(id)
    #implementation
  end
end
```

I struggle with testing `#save` and `.find`, I've:

```
describe '#save' do
  it 'saves the post' do
    subject.save
    created = Post.find(subject.id)
    expect(created).to eq(subject)
  end
end

describe '.find' do
  it 'finds the post' do
    subject.save
    created = Post.find(subject.id)
    expect(created).to eq(subject)
  end
end
```

In case of `#save` method I'd like to check side effect, in case of `.find` I'd like to test returned value. How to cope with this case without duplicating specs ?

Answer (score -1):

In this case, to isolate the `save` and `find` actions, you need to *mock the repository*.

Whether you are writing to a DB, a file-system, cache, or whatever - you can mock it to either expect the saving feature, or set it up (before the beginning of the test) to make sure `find` works.

For most repository implementations there are gems to mock them ([Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) for relational databases, [FakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) for file-system), but you can roll your own if you have some exotic repository no one has heard of.

This way you test `save` without using `find`, or vice versa.